# Changing the document title in React?

Tags: dom, reactjs

I'm trying to update the title of the document in a React app. I have very simple needs for this. The title is essentially used to put the `Total` component on display even when you're on a different tab.

This was my first instinct:

```
const React = require('react');

export default class Total extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    //otherstuff
    document.title = this.props.total.toString();
    console.log("Document title: ", document.title);
    return true;
  }
  render() {
    document.title = this.props.total;
    return (
      <div className="text-center">
        <h1>{this.props.total}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I thought this would just update the `document.title` every time this component was rendered, but it doesn't appear to do *anything*.

Not sure what I'm missing here. Probably something to do with how React runs this function - maybe somewhere that the `document` variable isn't available?

**EDIT:**

I'm starting a bounty for this question, as I still haven't found any solution. I've updated my code to a more recent version.

A weird development is that the `console.log` *does* print out the title I'm looking for. But for some reason, the actual title in the tab isn't updating. This issue is the same across Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: Are you doing universal rendering? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Nothing shows up in the console. And honestly, I don't know what you mean by 'universal rendering'.  I'm rendering exclusively in-browser, using `ReactDOM.render`.

Comment: A silly question maybe, but then your situation looks baffling... Does, by any chance, your page have frames? Do one other thing, in your component code, log the result of  `(window == top)` please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `webpack-dev-server` runs in an iframe mode by default:

https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#iframe-mode

So that might be why your attempts to set the title are failing. Try setting the `inline` option to true on `webpack-dev-server`, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 16):

Inside your `componentDidMount()` function in  `App.js` (or wherever), simply have:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "Amazing Page";
}
```

The reason this works is anywhere in your react project you have access to the Js global scope. Go ahead and type `window` in your sites console. Basically everything there you will be able to access in your React project.

Answer (score 15):

I now use [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) for this purpose, as it allows to customize different meta tags and links, and it also supports SSR.

```
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'

const Total = () => (
  <div className="text-center">
    <Helmet>
      <meta charSet="utf-8" />
      <title>{this.props.total}</title>
    </Helmet>
    <h1>{this.props.total}</h1>
  </div>
)
```

---

Original answer: there's actually a [package](https://github.com/gaearon/react-document-title) by gaeron for this purpose, but in a declarative way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DocumentTitle from 'react-document-title'

export default class Total extends Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <DocumentTitle title={this.props.total}>
        <div className='text-center'>
          <h1>{this.props.total}</h1>
        </div>
      </DocumentTitle>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, but it isn't working. `this.props.total` is a number, so at first I got an error relating to that. But now that is fixed and it just fails silently. The document title doesn't update.

Comment: Hum, how do you serve your application, using webpack?

Comment: What I am guessing is that `document.title` is not supported in your environment (like for example when you are on a file:// protocol)

Comment: Hm. I'm using `webpack-dev-server` - would that problem apply there? I will try to figure that out.

Comment: i use "Helmet" (enhanced 'react-document-title') and it works without any problems...  https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

Answer (score 5):

If the `react-document-title` package isn't working for you, the quick'n'dirty way to do that would be in a lifecycle method, probably both `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` (you can read more about those [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)):

So you would do something like:

```
const React = require('react');

export default class Total extends React.Component {

  // gets called whenever new props are assigned to the component
  // but NOT during the initial mount/render
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    document.title = this.props.total;
  }

  // gets called during the initial mount/render
  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = this.props.total;
  }

  render() {    
    return (
      <div className="text-center">
        <h1>{this.props.total}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I must be running into some bigger issue, as this also doesn't work. I tried putting a `console.log` in with them, and the functions are running, but for some reason `document.title = something` just isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way of dynamically changing document title with [`react-helmet`](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) package.

As a matter of fact you can dynamically change anything inside `<head>` tag using `react-helmet` from inside your component.

```
  const componentA = (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
       <Helmet>
        <title>Your dynamic document/page Title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Helmet application" />
       </Helmet>
       .....other component content
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To change title, meta tags and favicon dynamically at run time `react-helmet` provides a simple solution. You can also do this in `componentDidMount` using the standard document interface. In the example below I am using the same code for multiple sites, so helmet is looking for favicon and title from an environment variable

```
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { getAppStyles } from '../relative-path';
import { env } from '../relative-path';

<Helmet>
  <meta charSet="utf-8" />
  <title>{pageTitle[env.app.NAME].title}</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href={appStyles.favicon} />
</Helmet>
```